# frobenius norm and missing data

Tags: missing-data, error, matrix, norm

I'm calculating the frobenius norm on the differences between two matrices (so that I can minimize the result to reduce error). However, one of my initial matrices, and thus the difference matrix, contains missing data, which prevents me from calculating the frobenius norm.

I can't find the accepted convention when this happens. Do I just exclude the missing data points? Do I fill them with a constant value?

Comment: A third option is [tag:imputation].

Comment: I think I can have a lot of missing data, depending on how the matrices are made. I think imputation/interpolation would 'invent' too much data.

Comment: By the same token, replacing the missing data with some constant value will tend to under-state the variability in the data. Moreover, the deleting values won't bias the results if the missingness is non-informative, but it will reduce the sample size, and hence the power. The purpose of imputation is to try and ameliorate both of these downsides (but it may not always be possible for your variety of missing data).

Comment: What is your goal? Please tell us, as the question cannot be answered without knowing

Comment: I want to measure the similarity between two matrices. These are actually 2-D histograms, and the histograms will be calculated using different binsizes. Because of the nature of the data many bins equal zero, and as the binsize gets smaller many bins also start to be empty.

Comment: 0 isn't the same thing as missing.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of zeros AND some missing data.